# Msbuild pack ignores nuget packages with targets and task

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I have ProjectA and ProjectB

### ProjectA

Is a dotnet standard project with output and exe file to be used as as tool.
This generates a nuget package on build, using  property and  property to mark the package as a tool.
It also is marked as  to auto exclude from projects which installs the nuget package, when they them also generate a nuget package.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Net.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>ProjectA</AssemblyName>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <IsTool>true</IsTool>
    <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="build\ProjectA.props" Pack="True" PackagePath="build" />
      <None Include="build\net461\ProjectA.targets" Pack="True" PackagePath="build" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

#### ProjectA.targets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GetPackageVersionDependsOn>MyCustomTask;$(GetPackageVersionDependsOn)</GetPackageVersionDependsOn>
    <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="MyCustomTask">
    <!-- Idealy i would use a custom task to set PackageVersion to something different. Like 5.0.99-alpha1+102435 -->
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PackageVersion>5.0.99-alpha1+102435</PackageVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

### ProjectB

Installs a reference to the nuget package created by ProjectA.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net461</TargetFrameworks>
  <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="ProjectA" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When building ProjectB, the following files are genearted in obj/ folder:

- .csproj.nuget.g.props
- .csproj.nuget.g.targets

These files include import to ProjectA targets and props from the nuget package cache at:
%userprofile%.nuget\projecta\1.0.0\build\ProjectA.targets etc

Msbuild -t:pack ignores these imports when running, and hence the build ProjectB never sets the PackageVersion to 5.0.99-alpha1+102435 as i would expect.

Adding the above content of ProjectA.targets directly into ProjectB.csproj works.

Anyone have any suggestions what I'm missing or if the might be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `*.targets` to pack the nuget project into a nuget package based on that file, you should make this file recognized along with csproj file.

Based on the description, it seems that you used that targets file to pack your nuget project into a version `5.0.99`.

So you should make your `csproj` to work along with that file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
    <!--the path of the *.targets file-->
    <Import Project="xxx\xxx.targets"/>
</Project>
```

**Update 1**

[clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`) and `msbuild -t:pack ProjectB.csproj` to check it.

**Update 1**

Instead, modify Project B.csproj file:

use `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>` instead of `<TargetFrameworks>net461</TargetFrameworks>`.

The multi-platform framework seems to break the performance of the targets file, I'm also curious why this is happening. But this is the tip. You should use that.

Comment: I've updated my question, to better refect my setup, which should clarify that i do not have issue with generating a nuget package. But rather extending the msbuild -t:pack target to set custom properties during pack.

Comment: Did you clean the nuget caches first(delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`) and then run `msbuild -t:pack ProjectB.csproj`? If you have previous old nuget under that, it will always use the old rather then the new one.

Comment: Also, when you clean the nuget caches, please also delete `bin` and `obj` folder of Project B and then test again. And in my side with all your detailed info, I always get version `5.0.99-alpha1+102435` of `Project B`.

Comment: Did you have any update? I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Hi Perry, thanks for your suggestions. I cannot get it to work, when not importing explicitly <Import Include="..." />, even with your suggestions above. It does work, when i have not installed a nuget package that includes the targets files in build/*. The BeforeBuild and AfterBuild targets are picked up during build, but after build when pack runs, these targets files are ignored or simply not picked up during msbuild -t:pack

Comment: Hi Perry, I've created a sample project on github: https://github.com/rasmuseeg/NugetVersioningUsingTargets/tree/master
Open the sln and rebuild, manually update package reference in ProjectB to latest generated package from ProjectA using "this-project" source.
Watch the Output window in visual studio, ProjectB should generate a package version 1.3.3.7. But it does not.

Comment: @Rasmus-E, the issue is that you should use  `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>` rather than `<TargetFrameworks>net461</TargetFrameworks>`. The multi-platform framework seems to break the performance of the targets file, I'm also curious why this is happening. But this is the tip. You should use that.

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful. Sad that we cant use multi target frameworks. 
We might just not use auto nuget.g.props and nuget.g.targets. Instead have the targets files under a different folder then build of the nuget package.